# How to avoid breaking end-to-end encryption while employing cloud-based DDoS protection?

Tags: tls, proxy, ddos, cloud-computing, end-to-end-encryption

I have a few websites and apps that I need to protect from DDoS attacks. These websites and apps are delivered by various servers that sit in several small data centers around the world.

I'm thinking of getting some kind of cloud-based DDoS protection (Cloudflare, Akamai, Imperva, etc.) for this but these services require me to put them in between my servers and my users. The trouble with that is I want my users' traffic to still be end-to-end encrypted with TLS, and I'm not sure that's possible with these cloud-based DDoS protection services in between.

Based on Akamai's [Prolexic product brief](https://www.akamai.com/resources/product-brief/prolexic), it looks like there are at least two ways these DDoS protection services can sit between my servers and users: (1) **DNS redirection**, and (2) **BGP redirection**. I'm fairly sure DNS redirection will always break TLS, but I don't know how it might break or not break with the various ways BGP redirection can be implemented.

In the scenario that TLS could continue to end-to-end encrypt traffic, how would that affect the effectiveness of the DDoS protection service?

Comment: If you are only looking for DDoS protection (and not WAF service), then Cloudflare can protect your server from DDoS attacks by inspecting packets at layer 3/4, without having to MITM TLS connections to your server.  See https://www.cloudflare.com/products/cloudflare-spectrum/ for more info (note that one of the key features is 'Allow TLS passthrough traffic').  Cloudflare's full-blown WAF service, however, requires inspection of requests from clients, so this requires them to MITM the TLS connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a **DNS protection** you dont need to share your TLS keys with the providers, basically a DNS redirection is that the DNS will point to their servers and then they forward the traffic. This solution dont needs to share the TLS keys. For the **BGP solution** is the same but the main difference is that is at layer3 (IP). The provider will anonunce the IP prefix and make the drop on their cloud and then they will forward you the clean IP packets.

Im not entering on whats better of the two approaches, but for your solution both methods will work with no problem